# Creating 2 files and writing to them different content from another file in Lisp

Tags: file, io, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write in 2 different files content from another file. Procedure is that I have to write 10 lines of `file_a` in one file and the rest in the another file.

here is the code:

```
(defun makeFiles (&optional (nb 1))
                 (setq file_A
                     (open "fr_chars.txt"
                              :direction :input
                              :if-does-not-exist :error))
                 (setq file_B
                     (open "chars_1.txt"
                              :direction :output
                              :if-does-not-exist :create
                              :if-exists :supersede))
                 (setq file_C
                     (open "chars_2.txt"
                              :direction :output
                              :if-does-not-exist :create
                              :if-exists :supersede))

                 (loop
                     (cond
                         ((equal (read-line file_A) nil) (close file_A) (close file_B) (close file_C) (return 0))
                         ((equal (length (read-line file_B)) 10)
                         (princ (read-from-string file_A) file_B))
                         (terpri file_B)
                         (princ "HERE ARE FR CHARS" file_B)
                         (princ (read-from-string file_A) file_C)
                         (terpri file_B)
                         (terpri file_C)
                         (setq nb (1+ nb)) ) ) )
```

Having the `file_a`, the code creates the 2 files but I don't arrive to write in those files as said (10 lines in `file_a` and rest in the another).

Comment: how is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42747269/850781)? Please do _NOT_ ask new questions, edit the existing question instead.  It is still unclear what the problem is (IOW, I cannot parse your phrase "I dont arrive to write in those files as said" - this is not English and I am not a native English speaker either, so please do not rely on my ESP :-).

Comment: ok @sds. I don't find how to write differently. I agree my english is poor.

Comment: i got it. maybe the problem was there not making the right question.  here is the code i was looking for  (loop
      (cond
        ((equal debut 20) (close fichier1)(close fichier2) (close fichier3)(return 0))
          (t (princ debut fichier2)
             (terpri fichier2)
             (princ (read-char fichier3) fichier2)
             (terpri fichier2)
             (princ debut fichier1)
             (terpri fichier1)
             (princ (read-char fichier3) fichier1)
             (terpri fichier1)
             (incf debut) ) ) ) ) )

Comment: I suggest that you start with compiling you code. Compiler warnings will tell you a lot about what you are doing wrong. Second, you should format your code properly - it is absolutely unreadable now.

Comment: Very good, I did not know this, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Nitpicks

1. Using [`open`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_open.htm)/[`close`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_close.htm) directly is almost always wrong. Use [`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm) instead to ensure that the file is closed no matter what.
2. When comparing numbers, use [`=`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eq_sle.htm) instead of [`equal`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equal.htm).
3. It is not a good idea to specify default argument explicitly (e.g., `:if-does-not-exist :error` for `:direction :input`) because it increases clutter and reduces code readability.
4. `(read-line stream)` *never* returns `nil`. It either returns a `string`, or signals an the `end-of-stream` error.  Please read the manual or see my code below on how to call it properly.

## Code

```
(defun split-first-lines (source num-lines destination-1 destination-2)
  "Read SOURCE, writing the first NUM-LINES to DESTINATION-1
and the rest to DESTINATION-2"
  (with-open-file (in source)
    (with-open-file (out destination-1 :direction :output)
      (loop :repeat num-lines
        :do (write-line (read-line in) out)))
    (with-open-file (out destination-2 :direction :output)
      (loop :for line = (read-line in nil nil) :while line
        :do (write-line line out)))))
```

## Required Reading

1. [`read-line`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_lin.htm)
2. [`write-line`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_stg.htm)
3. [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm)

## Homework

What would happen if the `source` file contains fewer than `num-lines` lines?

What is the desired behavior?

How would you fix the bug?

Comment: Default arguments may be given explicitly if not obvious.  I do not see that as an absolute.

Comment: @Svante: after a while the defaults do become obvious :-)

Comment: thanks a lot for ur good answer and explaination. I am exercising.